# Need help with TSQL proc

Tags: t-sql

So I have a mapping table of tournaments to teams. All this table has is TeamId and TournamentId.

I have a proc, GetTournamentsByTeam that takes in @TeamId int

Basically I want to get all the tournament records from tblTournament using all the TournamentId's I get from the mapping table where the TeamId = @TeamId.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is an [inner join](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7114.asp) between the tables.

```
SELECT     tournament.*
FROM       tblTournament tournament
INNER JOIN tblTournamentTeams tt ON tournament.TournamentId = tt.TournamentId
WHERE      tt.TeamId = @TeamId
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is read any SQL book for beginners. Seriously.